# all but.. none but.. usage

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, confusables

I'm a bit confused with the usage of *all but* and *none but*:

> 1. "*We are all but defenseless*" – should mean we are **definitely** defenseless?
> 2. "*None but misfortunes follow*" – **only** misfortunes follow?

Were *all but* and *none but* used correctly here?

How do you use them correctly? There seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: For *all but*, I would word the direct version as *we have only our [weak] defenses left*

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of "all but" is "everything, except", or "almost". Therefore, "all but defenseless" means "everything except defenseless" or "almost defenseless".

Similarly, the meaning of "none but" is "nothing, except", or "only". Therefore, "none but misfortunes" means "nothing except misfortunes" or "only misfortunes".

They're used correctly in those sentences, and there's *supposed* to be a contrast between "*all* but" and "*none* but".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that definitely clears it up. :) Thanks!

Comment: Wait what? "everything except defenseless" means that you are not defenseless at all, right? I mean, here's a list of "all" (not really, but for the sake of argument) things related to defense: (defenseless, moderately armoured, tough, impenetrable, invincible). Let's see, you're _all but_ defenseless, so that means you are not defenseless, but you _are_ moderately armoured, tough, impenetrable and/or invincible. So, _all but_ defenseless logically implies you are actually not at all defenseless, following this explanation, right? What am I misunderstanding here?